# Is it possible to dump a whole Lua module's state on disk and load later in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I'm trying to use Lua script as an extension language for my C++ program. I'm wondering if it's possible to load a module script, execute some functions and then dump the current module's state (or stack?) on disk. Later I can load from it and resume the execution? Is that possible with Lua's available C interfaces?

Thanks!

---

Add more context to make it clear based on comments.

Say my module has a bunch of variables (majorly tables) and functions. Those functions will change the value of tables.

My goal is after some function calls, I wanna dump (serialize) those variables (states) into disk and load from it later. Actually I don't need to dump those functions.

Comment: If the state is composed of plain values (strings, numbers, booleans), then you can stored it in a table and save it. If you want to stop mid execution of a function, then no.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "module's state". Is the state a table or some set of local or global variables? Most module scripts just return a table with functions, so they don't have their own state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the asking. I added more context in original questions. Yeah. I just wanna dump some variable's values

Comment: See http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this with the stock PUC-Rio implementation of Lua, but there are alternative implementations that support it. One such implementation is [Eris](https://github.com/fnuecke/eris), which is used by the OpenComputers Minecraft mod for exactly this purpose. Just make your code run in a coroutine, then yield and persist the thread.